# Property 'itemsNav' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I don't understand what's wrong with itemsNav.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { list } from '../../constants/NAV';

const itemsNav = ref(list)

</script>

                <li 
                    v-for="item of itemsNav"
                    :key="item.id"
                >
                    {{ item.label }}
                </li>
```

```
interface NavList {
    id?: number,
    label?: string,
    link?: string,
}

export const list: NavList[] = [
    {id: 1, label: 'худшие компании', link: '#'},
    {id: 2, label: 'новости', link: '#'},
    {id: 3, label: 'о проекте', link: '#'},
]
```

I realize there's something wrong with NAV.ts. I tried to leave only const nav = [1, 2, 3] and it didn't help either

Looked at the responses from other similar queries, but didn't find the right one. It seems that TypeScript rolled out a new update where they added some kind of validation

Comment: Add type to your ref. ref<NavList[]>(list)

Answer (score 0):

As per `ref()` [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref) it returns object with `.value` field. Try use like this `v-for="item of itemsNav.value"`

Comment: The error persists :(

Comment: @Alex can you create stackblitz example?

Comment: Yeah, except there's no Vue(typeScript) there

https://vue-tmxbuo.stackblitz.io

Comment: I couldn't start your example because if complains to `main.js` file. I tried locally in vue application created by Vite and it worked fine.

Comment: So there's no mistake? Could you please tell me what plugins you have for vue + ts?

Comment: Take a look at this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-starter-mgjwtl?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FNav.vue

Comment: The error was in yarn 4. I created a project from scratch on pnpm, updated with the current component and there is no error.